# Apache shiro how to filter a api according to its method?

Tags: apache, filter, shiro

I am using Apache shiro in my project. It provides some default filters to filter url. Now I come across a problem about filtering url. If has API like '/rest/user/info', if its method is 
GET, this api can be visited by anyone, but if it is POST it just can be visited by admin. I found the dafault filter 'rest' but it helps nothing. Does anyone can give some advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

config like this:

```
<property name="filterChainDefinitions">
  <value>
     /login = authc
     /logout = logout
     /rest/user/info = rest[user:info]
  </value>
</property>
```

1. post /rest/user/info needs perms[user:info:create]
2. get  /rest/user/info needs perms[user:info:read]
3. ...

---

give admin perms[user:info:create] and perms[user:info:read],give others only perms[user:info:read]. set user's permissions in doGetAuthorizationInfo method of Realm.

```
protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals) {
        SimpleAuthorizationInfo info = new SimpleAuthorizationInfo();
        info.addStringPermission("user:info:create");
        info.addStringPermission("user:info:read");
        return info;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for reply you so late for some reasons, thanks a lot, with your example I read the document again I find something helpful, thanks